# ! Argument of \@Aboxed has an extra }

Tags: align, mathtools

I have a problem using `\Aboxed` in the following `align*`-environment:

```
\begin{align*}
\omega(\sigma_{ij}) &\equiv 1 - \left(\frac{27J_3}{2\sigma_e^3}\right)^2 \\
& = \omega(L) = 1 - \frac{\left( 9L - L^3\right)^2}{\left(L^2+3\right)^3}. 
\end{align*}
```

I want to use `\Aboxed` to put the last part of the final equation in a box, i.e.

```
\begin{align*}
\omega(\sigma_{ij}) &\equiv 1 - \left(\frac{27J_3}{2\sigma_e^3}\right)^2 \\
& = \Aboxed{ \omega(L) = 1 - \frac{\left( 9L - L^3\right)^2}{\left(L^2+3\right)^3}. }
\end{align*}
```

This gives me the error message in the title. However, using `\Aboxed` in the upper equation of the `align*` doesn't cause any problems at all. I've also used `\Aboxed` in the last equation of other `align*`'s and `align`'s in my document. What causes the error in this case?

Answer (score 10):

`\Aboxed` (From `mathtools`) is designed to put a box across an alignment point (Refer `mathtools` documentation, section- 3.4.5, page 18). Hence,

```
\Aboxed{\omega(\sigma_{ij}) &\equiv 1 - \left(\frac{27J_3}{2\sigma_e^3}\right)^2 }\
```

works. The `\Aboxed` command is defined as (from `mathtools.sty`)

```
\newcommand\Aboxed[1]{\@Aboxed#1\ENDDNE}
\def\@Aboxed#1&#2\ENDDNE{%
  \settowidth\@tempdima{$\displaystyle#1{}$}%
  \addtolength\@tempdima{\fboxsep}%
  \addtolength\@tempdima{\fboxrule}%
  \global\@tempdima=\@tempdima
  \kern\@tempdima
  &
  \kern-\@tempdima
  \boxed{#1#2}
}
```

Hence, when you use `\Aboxed`, TeX will greedily look for an `&` (alignment character) and when it is not found, an error is returned.

If you want a box only for a portion without an alignment point inside, you can use `boxed` (basically from `amsmath` and `mathtools` loads `amsmath` also) as

```
& = \boxed{ \omega(L) = 1 - \frac{\left( 9L - L^3\right)^2}{\left(L^2+3\right)^3}. }
```

The `boxed` command is defined as (from `amsmath.sty`)

```
\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

which does not have any concern for the alignment character `&`. (Hence it will not work across `&`.)

**Conclusion:** If you want a box to cross through an alignment point, use `\Aboxed`. On the other hand, if the box is for only a portion without alignment point, use `\boxed`

Complete MWE will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Aboxed{\omega(\sigma_{ij}) &\equiv 1 - \left(\frac{27J_3}{2\sigma_e^3}\right)^2 }\\
& = \boxed{ \omega(L) = 1 - \frac{\left( 9L - L^3\right)^2}{\left(L^2+3\right)^3}. }
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for a thorough answer.

Comment: @ChristianDalheimØien: If the answer has solved your problem , you may consider accepting it (by clicking the green check mark below voting symbols) and also upvote it. That is how we say `thanks' here in TeX.SX.