# How `\Aboxed` works?

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

As a requirement in a homework I was asked to enclose my answers with a red box, so I imported `mathtools` and `xcolor` and tried with:

```
\color{red}\Aboxed{\color{black}#1}
```

where `#1` is the equation, but it doesn't work. So I decided to watch the implementation of `mathtools` and I found the definition of `\Aboxed{}` that is:

```
\newcommand\Aboxed[1]{\let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`}\@Aboxed#1&&\ENDDNE}

\def\@Aboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi \setbox \z@
    \hbox{$\displaystyle#1{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule }%
    \edef\@tempa {\kern  \wd\z@ &\kern -\the\wd\z@ \fboxsep
        \the\fboxsep \fboxrule \the\fboxrule }\@tempa \boxed {#1#2}%
}
```

I think that I understand `\setbox` and a part of `\@tempa`.
I made a little drawing about what I think is happening there, `\setbox` creates a box with width of what will be on the left side of the equation accessible by `\wd\z@`. Then `\@tempa` puts that kerning on the left side, after that the alignment symbol, but I have no idea about the negative kerning on the right side.
[image: tikz example of the kern]
But I can't find anything about `` \let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`} ``, or the command `\ENDDNE` or the if statement `` \ifnum0=`{}\fi ``. I'm asking a lot but if someone can explain me that or give me any good place to start I would be grateful.

Comment: The width of `\z@` (as a box) is the width of the left part of the alignment including the line width and sep from the box. Next we come to `\@tempa`. Once executed we essentially have ` \kern  \wd\z@ & \kern -\wd\z@ \boxed{#1#2}`. The idea is to use the normal `\boxed` construction to make the boxed line, but then we need to pull this backwards such that the `#1` part matches up as if we were actually using alignment. The kern on the left of the `&` make sure that the width of that entry is actually correct, else align might not center correctly.

Comment: Then comes the moving the box backwards. The amount we need is the width of the left part of the alignment plus the box line width and box sep, which is exactly what is in the box `\z@`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: if you want a coloured version of `\Aboxed`, here is a quick fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Acolorboxed[2][red]{%
   \let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`}%
   \@Acolorboxed{#1}#2&&\ENDDNE
}
\def\@Acolorboxed#1#2&#3&#4\ENDDNE{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\displaystyle#2{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule}%
  \edef\@tempa{\kern\wd\z@ & \kern-\the\wd\z@ \fboxsep\the\fboxsep \fboxrule\the\fboxrule}%
  \@tempa
  \fcolorbox{#1}{white}{\m@th$\displaystyle#2#3$}%
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Aboxed{a&=b} \\
\Acolorboxed{a&=b} \\
\Acolorboxed[green]{a&=b}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explaining `\Aboxed`

This is trickier: let me first "simplify" the definition by removing the two brace tricks (see later for that), i.e. let us assume the definitions were simply

```
\newcommand\Aboxed[1]{\@Aboxed#1&&\ENDDNE}
\def\@Aboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#1{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule}%
  \edef\@tempa{\kern\wd0 & \kern-\the\wd0 \fboxsep=\the\fboxsep \fboxrule=\the\fboxrule}%
  \@tempa
  \boxed {#1#2}%
}
```

The definition

```
\def\@Aboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE{...}
```

means that `\@Aboxed` expects *delimited* arguments. Everything up to the first `&` is the first argument; everything between the first and second `&` is the second argument; everything between the second `&` and `\ENDDNE` is the third argument. The macro `\ENDDNE` is just some dummy delimiter. However, these two `&` and this `\ENDDNE` *must* be there: TeX will keep scanning the file until it finds them, and they're not there you'll get trouble, and that's why `\Aboxed` puts it there. You could have defined

```
\def\Aboxed#1&#2&#3\MaryPoppins{...}
```

and that would not have changed a thing, provided of course you correspondingly used

```
\newcommand\Aboxed[1]{\@Aboxed#1&&\MaryPoppins}
```

The fact that `\Aboxed` puts *two* `&` after its argument is a safety measure, which I presume was not present in first versions of `mathtools` (see [! Argument of \@Aboxed has an extra }](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55341/82917)). It allows you to (ab)use it and write `\Aboxed{a}` with no `&` without raising errors (though you should simply use `\boxed` for that).

Let us make an example: TeX expands macros, and when it finds

```
\Aboxed{E&=mc^2}
```

this is expanded to

```
% remember:
% \def\@Aboxed#1&#2&#3\ENDDNE
\@Aboxed E&=mc^2&&\ENDDNE
```

so that here `E` is the first argument, `=mc^2` is the second argument, and a stray `&` is the third one. By the definition of `\@Aboxed` this becomes now

```
\setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle E{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule}%
\edef\@tempa{\kern\wd0 & \kern-\the\wd0 \fboxsep=\the\fboxsep \fboxrule=\the\fboxrule}%
\@tempa
\boxed {E=mc^2}%
```

The box register `\box0` contains then the `E` plus the width of the `\fbox` and the separation. The idea is now to

1. insert invisible horizontal space equal to the width of `\box0`,
2. go to the next column,
3. go back the width of `\box0`,
4. print the `\boxed` equation.

Why the `\edef`? Cells act like groups, and the `\box0` is set in a cell. If we had written

```
kern\wd0 & \kern-\wd0 \boxed {E=mc^2}
```

then the negative `\kern` would've been wrong. The `\edef` makes sure that `\the` is expanded such that we have the correct value. (Question: Why not using `\global\setbox\@ne`?)

**The brace tricks**, i.e. the two bits `` \let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`} `` and `` \ifnum0=`{}\fi ``, are rather tricky. You can read something e.g. in [Showcase of brace tricks: }, \egroup, \iffalse{\fi}, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9897/82917). My grasp of brace tricks is limited but I think it boils down to the fact that TeX does not increase/decrease the master counter when it scans `` `{ `` and `` `} ``. I assume they are there for some safety reason but honestly my tests haven't shown any difference without them. Hopefully someone with more TeX knowledge than me will shed light on this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot to understand what happens there. I'm just not really clear in the left spacing part in `\@tempa`, why does it includes `\kern-\the\wd0 \fboxsep=\the\fboxsep \fboxrule=\the\fboxrule` when it can just put `\kern-\the\wd0`?

Comment: @AmadoC I am not sure either. It might a safety measure against someone/something redefining them, but it's only a guess.

Comment: Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

I propose to define a `\colorboxed` command, based on the `\fcolorbox` command, from `xcolor`, with two mandatory arguments (the line colour and the contents of the box), and an optional argument for the background colour (white by default), and to patch the `\Aboxed` command with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\colorboxed}[3][white]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
    \xpatchcmd{\@Aboxed}{\boxed}{\colorboxed[LavenderBlush!40]{IndianRed}}{}{}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x & = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
\Aboxed{x & = \frac{-b'\pm\sqrt{b'^2-ac}}{a}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]